# Zend Framework 3 routing for all controller

Tags: controller, action, router, zend-framework3

I want to solve following issue in Zend Framework 3:

Routing for all controller and action in module.config.php without writing any controller in the module.config.php file.

Example: I don't want to write ContactController here:

```
return [
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'app' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/app[/:action][/]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'contact' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/contact[/:action][/]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\ContactController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

];

Answer (score 1):

you have to set module.config like this

```
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'application' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/application/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => [
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller', //这个好像是必须的
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
        'invokables' => [
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        ],
    ],
```

]

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Router is to match a request's URL to a route and dispatch the request to the defined controller and action.  You have to define a controller for each route otherwise what would the MVC do when it matches the URL to the route?